# Creating a Tree relationship in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I'm striving to make this simple thing: I want a tree relationship (forget about performance, it is gonna be shallow, no more than 2 -3 levels). I tried this:

@Entity
@Table(name = "BASE")
public class BaseEBean {

```
int id;
String text;

BaseEBean parent;

Set<BaseEBean> children = new HashSet<BaseEBean>();

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "TEXT")
public String getText() {
    return text;
}
public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

@ManyToOne
@Cascade(value = { CascadeType.ALL })
public BaseEBean getParent() {
    return parent;
}
public void setParent(BaseEBean parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public Set<BaseEBean> getChildren() {
    return children;
}
public void setChildren(Set<BaseEBean> children) {
    this.children = children;
}
```

}

I tested it by instanting two beans A and B. Saving A. Setting A as B's parent. Saving B. Then loading from db A. I was expecting the set to contain B, but no luck. Children property will have size() = 0. I didn't even try to delete.. but I am pessimistic.

Help?

Comment: Have you checked your database to see if A and B are persisted?

Comment: Also try pulling out just B and see if A is listed as its parent, this will help give us a better idea of whats happening.

Comment: If I do that in another session, shutting down the existing one, both A and B will be allright. So?